# not able to select multiple files or select all files in a directory

Tags: java, android, user-interface, filesystems

I am preparing a music app where i have to add multiple music files to my list. I want to pick one or multiple or all files in  a folder.

I am trying the following code:

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("music/*");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 10);
```

Updated question:

[image]

I can only pick one file. I have esexplorer and android file manager.

Comment: `EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE` is a request, not a command. Not every `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` implementation will honor it. Also, `music/*` is not a valid wildcard MIME type (try `audio/*`, if you are looking for audio files).

Comment: will android native file manager honot it.  Or you know any file manager which honors it

Comment: I do not know what you consider the "android native file manager" to be. If you mean something that [resembles this](https://commonsware.com/misc/saf.png), then yes, that supports `EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE`, unless the device manager changed things.

Comment: I not able to select multiple files from the android file manager. The updated question shows the image